# Choose User Profile DB on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: user-profile-service

We have 2 User Profile Service application in our environment. Early created User profile service is not provisioning with user synchronization service and not working now. Last created User profile service is working normally, but our sharepoint is getting user data from old (not working) user profile service.

Is it possible to choose User profile DB on sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop(disable) existing UPSA in Central Administration or via PowerShell, remove service then create new User Profile Service and set database name while creating.

To create new User Profile Service you need to use PowerShell cmdlet New-SPProfileServiceApplication with the flag -ProfileDBName.

[More about New-SPProfileServiceApplication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/New-SPProfileServiceApplication?view=sharepoint-ps)